# Where does Magento decrement quantity of a product after the order is placed?

Tags: magento2, checkout, quantity, order-success-page

I need to check the Product Salable Quantity of a product after a successful order to change one of the product´s attributes.

I keep getting the product salable quantity before It´s decremented. Where can I insert my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use Controller fired after proper event.

Event can be fired before:

```
sales_quote_item_qty_set_after
```

Or

```
sales_quote_item_set_product
```

Model:

```
app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Item.php
```

Interesting explanation what is Magento Quote.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612100/what-is-a-magento-quote

List of events:

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/use-event-magento-2/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the Magento 2.3.X.

but for  2.2.X and 2.1.X versions, Stock deduction happen on order place from

**Magento_CatalogInventory** module.

> The method **registerProductsSale** of
>   `Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockManagement` is responsiable for
>   stock deduction.

This  method is called from `Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\SubtractQuoteInventoryObserver` observer on

`sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` event.

And

`Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\CheckoutAllSubmitAfterObserver` observer on

`checkout_submit_all_after` event.

***For your requirement, you have to work on these two observer classes.***